# Material-ui button within react only responds to onClick events within it's padding

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

Now sure if it's because of how these functions are being due to the arrow function (as each time I use this function, the state is refreshed from my understand).

I am trying to create a class to calls a functional component that can display many buttons). In doing so I wanted to get the information if the back to parent class and do something depending on the call.

I found something really strange, where if I click off to the side of the button (far left/right edges and corners) it always works, the method is called. If you click on the center of the button it returns undefined.

I made a demo here to see it in action: https://codesandbox.io/embed/blue-field-f9hyq?fontsize=14

Here is the sample functional component and class that are incorporated in this test:

```
function ButtonList(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const onClick = e => {
    props.onClick(e);
  };
  return (
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      className={classes.button}
      name="createEvent"
      onClick={e => onClick(e)}
    >
      Create Event
    </Button>
  );
}

class App extends Component {
  handleClick = e => {
    if (e.target.name === "createEvent") {
      console.log("event clicked");
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <ButtonList onClick={e => this.handleClick(e)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I further investigated by removing the padding, which again caused an undefined return. I cranked the padding up and the onClick worked only within the padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because Material render a span inside a button that has no attribute name.

```
<button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-contained" tabindex="0" type="button" name="createEvent">
  <span class="MuiButton-label">
    Create Event
  </span>
  <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
</button>
```

And your click event handler has a condition on the name attribute of the element being click.

```
    if (e.target.name === "createEvent") {
      console.log("event clicked");
    }
```

Comment: Thats so strange. How would onClick events ever trigger if the span is within the bounds?

Comment: The span does not fill the whole button, as you an see here: https://snipboard.io/y1bg4o.jpg

Comment: You can try this to see: `handleClick = e => {
    if (e.target.name === "createEvent") {
      console.log("event clicked");
    }
    console.log("button clicked");
  };`

Comment: Yes, I see that worked. I think that makes things a bit more complicated but thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's the downside of working with a library like Material UI